# for loops and snippets where we reassign variables

Tags: java, loops

The task is: write a program that swaps the maximum and minimum elements of a given array. Print the array before and after this operation.

I am still a huge noob at programming, most of the time I just can't really picture what the codes are doing.

```java
public class problem6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[15];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
/*
I don't think I really understand incrementation in loops, what exactly do they do? As far as I understand 
it is like having an industry line? I suppose 'i' would be the product and '++' would be the thing that 
carries 'i' to the be checked one by one? I really need an ape analogy because I can't really visualize it.
*/
            arr[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 15);

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");
        System.out.println();

        int minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 0; //why do we assign min and max to 0 and not any other number?
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[minIndex] > arr[i])
                minIndex = i;
            if (arr[maxIndex] < arr[i])
                maxIndex = i;
/*
I see a lot of codes like:

if (arr[minIndex] > arr[i])
                minIndex = i;
            if (arr[maxIndex] < arr[i])
                maxIndex = i;
what purpose does it serve? For the lack of knowledge and from a really noob programmer's perspective
it seems like we are "reassigning" minIndex and maxIndex to 'i', which is probably not what we're actually doing
but I don't know how to describe it other way.
*/
        }
        System.out.println(minIndex + " " + arr[minIndex]);
        System.out.println(maxIndex + " " + arr[maxIndex]);


        {

            int tmp = arr[minIndex];
            arr[minIndex] = arr[maxIndex];
            arr[maxIndex] = tmp;
/*
Here again, for the lack of understanding and better way of describing, it seems to me that we are reassigning,
which makes it appear illogical to me, but I'd assume it's not actually "reassigning".

int tmp = arr[minIndex];
            arr[minIndex] = arr[maxIndex];
            arr[maxIndex] = tmp;
*/
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to learn Java, before trying to use it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What is `i`, what does it do and what does `i++` mean:**

`i` is used in this loop to indicate how many times you've looped through said loop.

The `++` is there to do `i + 1` after each time you've looped trough the for loop.

For better understanding on how you use `i` in your example, imagine the array `arr` being a big book and what you write in the `[]` is which page you want to open. In the loop you basically flip through the book to each pagenumber in those brackets.

**Why does `minIndex` and `maxIndex` get set to 0 instead of any other number?**

They get set to `0` because we can assume that that is the lowest possible Index in your array. So when the Index gets compared to any other possible number that could be the lowest or highest Index, it always gets set to said lowest or highest Index instead of always having the same value you set because no other value in your array is higher or lower than that.

**Why do we make `arr[minIndex]` assert the same value as `arr[maxIndex]`?**

In your question's title you said that you wanted to swap the highest number in your array with the lowest number. So now that we have found the highest and lowest number in your array these steps switch the two.

If you have any other questions or if any of my descriptions are unclear, just comment under the answer and I'll do my best to help you out. Also, don't look down on yourself so much. Everyone was a "noob" at some point :)

Comment: About the last part, where we make arr[minIndex] assert the same value as arr[maxIndex].

We declare int tmp = arr[minIndex]
is this so that later when we want arr[maxIndex] to assert the same value as arr[minIndex] we don't get an error?

as in, we need to assign arr[minIndex] to some other name, because if we say
arr[maxIndex] = arr[minIndex] we will get an error?

Comment: sorry I don't know how to jump to the next line. It's all clumped up.

Comment: Well as an example, lets say that `arr[minIndex]` would have a value of 5 and the value of `arr[maxIndex]` has a value of 15. The part where `int tmp` gets set as the same value as `arr[minIndex]` is there because in the step after that you overwrite it with the value of `arr[maxIndex]` and we don't want to lose that value yet so we write it into a temporary variable. After `arr[minIndex]` gets overwritten with the value of `arr[maxIndex]` (so now it is not 5 anymore but 15) we do the same for `arr[maxIndex]` by overwriting it with the value of `arr[minIndex]` so now it's value is not 15 but 5

Comment: @veryshite you don't necessarily get an error. But since you overwrite `arr[minIndex]` with the value of `arr[maxIndex]` if you'd do `arr[maxIndex] = arr[minIndex]` you'd just overwrite 15 with 15 instead of overwriting 15 with 5 because `arr[minIndex]` is already the same value as `arr[maxIndex]` at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is quick fix for you.

Following is complete example of swaps the maximum and minimum elements of a given array.

**Input :**

Enter elements you want to input in array: 
5

Enter all the elements:
10
15
16
1
9

**Output :**

Element After swaps :
10
15
1
16
9

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Scanner scan = null;
        int number;
        try {
            scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter elements you want to input in array: ");
            number = scan.nextInt();
            int array[] = new int[number];
            System.out.println("Enter all the elements:");

            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                array[i] = scan.nextInt();
            }
            int[] resultArray = swap(array);
            System.out.println("Element After swaps :");
            for (int i : resultArray) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            scan.close();
        }
    }

    public static int[] swap(int[] array) {
        int minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; ++i) {
            if (array[i] < array[minIndex])
                minIndex = i;
            if (array[i] > array[maxIndex])
                maxIndex = i;
        }
        int t;
        if (maxIndex != minIndex) {
            t = array[minIndex];
            array[minIndex] = array[maxIndex];
            array[maxIndex] = t;
        }
        return array;
    }
```

Hope this solution works.
Please mark as answer if this solution is helpful.